# Superposition of waves to find a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, wave-equation

I am in trouble to understand the "spirit" of the following discussion that my teacher wrote on his notes.

Consider
$$\ddot q_k=-\omega_0^2q_k-a(2q_k-q_{k+1}-q_{k-1})\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$
with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. My teacher said that to find the solution of this equation one can proceed to *find the normal modes and then write the general solution by superposition*.

So he became to consider the function $q_k(t)= e^{i\omega t}e^{isk}$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$, where $e^{isk}$ is the *spatial term* and $e^{i\omega t}$ is the *oscillatory term*.

Then he put the function $q_k(t)$ into the $(1)$ to have a relation that $\omega$ must satisfy (skipping the calculation):
$$\omega=\omega(s)=\pm \sqrt{\omega_0^2+4asin^2 \frac{s}{2}}$$
So for any value of $s$ one have two solution
$$e^{i\omega(s) t}e^{isk}\qquad\qquad e^{-i\omega(s) t}e^{isk}.$$

Now *to build a general solution one can write a superposition of the "waves" found*:
$$q_k(t) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a(s)e^{i(\omega(s) t+sk)}+b(s)e^{i(-\omega(s)t+sk)}ds.$$

So ( outside all the question under the use of certain type of language like *waves, normal mode* that I think are linked to the fact that this is some kind of generalization of waves equation - if someone want to say something about this, I will happy - ) my really question is:

What is the spirit under the fact the constructed $q_k(t)$ is a solution of (1)? Why does that integral appear?

Answer (score 1):

The equation is linear: linear combinations of solutions are still solutions.

If you have say finitely many solutions, then you can obtain further solutions by taking a linear combination of these (that is, a finite linear combination).

But in your case you have infinitely many solutions, and so the next step can be to consider the integral of a continuum of solutions since it is a generalization of the notion of linear combination now with the coefficients $a(s)$ and $b(s)$.

**Indeed, the integral that you wrote is again a solution of the original equation.**

Comment: Ok, thank you @John B . I would to investigate some more about this generalization: how is known in the literature? I can't figure out the step "consider the integral" because I never seen this kind of generalization of linear combination. What does the integral gives me more than a finite and simple linear combination?

Comment: Ok, thank you @John B